# Scrollable and zoomable view with webviews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

Let me start by saying - I know there are quite a lot of posts on this issue. I've been digging and testing it quite a bit, but couldn't come up with the proper solution to my specific requirements.

I need to have a master view with several webviews inside it, and more than one should be visible at a single moment. For this master view - I need to be able to scroll it (to reveal invisible webviews) and to zoom (in order to focus on a single webview).

I've tried TableLayout, but had problems with the zoom (and painting issues with the scrolling). I've tried scroll views, but also read it's not recommended.

Any ideas or recommendation regarding how to achieve this?

Thanks,
yakobom

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach could be to have only one webview with the root html doc containing multiple iframes. Load each page in one of the iframes.

This way the scrolling/zooming could be handled by the webview itself.

Comment: Hi, I must admit this is a very interesting suggestion! But I'm afraid it will not work for me. I need to have several web pages like a table, one next to the other ( but not joined with it) and one above the other. And I must keep original web pages layouts.

Comment: I didn't understand. You can always have the iframes arranged in what ever layout you want in the main app. You can use colspan with tables or simple use absolute positioning in css

Comment: Perhaps I cannot explain more than this, but I need different webviews. Still, a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollable view can be achieved by adding a scroll view in .xml file and placing remaining text views, edit texts in that scroll view..

Comment: Adi, I have tried scroll views and it did not work well. Perhaps with other views there is not problem, but with web views there is.

Answer (score 0):

to scrolling webview:

```
 mWebView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView2.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
 mWebView2.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
 mWebView2.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
 mWebView2.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
```

to zooming webview:

```
webView.setInitialScale(50);
webPlanSettings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
webPlanSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: Thanks man - but please read what I asked again. The problem is not really zooming the webview itself. I have several webviews inside other view, and I'm zooming that view. The size (and content) of the webviews should change accordingly, and that is the problem. I'm trying to figure out how to do it and what type this parent view should be.